# networkx add_nodes Execute exception

Tags: networkx

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_nodes_from([2,3])
```

now，G already have 3 nodes, I added 10 nodes

```
H=nx.path_graph(10)
G.add_nodes_from(H)
G.number_of_nodes()
```

but G.number_of_nodes()=10，why? where is the nodes[1,2,3]?
thanks!

Comment: Have you actually looked into what the nodes of G are? Also, what exception are you talking about in the title?

Answer (score 0):

G is a graph containing the integers 1, 2, and 3 as nodes (and no edges):

```
1   2   3
```

H is a graph containing the integers 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9 as nodes.

```
0--1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8--9
```

Since `G.nodes()` is a subset¹ of `H.nodes()`,  `G.nodes()` equals `H.nodes()` after  `G.add_nodes_from(H)`

¹) technically, it's implemented as a list.